# Как создать и записать данные в CSV?

Tags: node.js, csv

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать и записать данные в CSV?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `node.js` есть пакет `csv`, устанавливаем:

```
npm install csv
```

И записываем (в данном случае в `stdout`):

```
var csv = require('csv');

csv.generate({seed: 1, columns: 2, length: 20})
  .pipe(csv.parse())
  .pipe(csv.transform(function(record){
     return record.map(function(value){
       return value.toUpperCase()
     });
  }))
  .pipe(csv.stringify ())
  .pipe(process.stdout);
```

В случае с записью в файл просто открываем файл и передаём его хэндлер вместо `process.stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

csv формат прост как пень. Весь смысл в том что у нас есть ряды и колонки. Как определяются ряды? Простым переносом строки. Как определяется колонка? Ряд разделяется каким-то разделителем, наиболее частый это точка с запятой. Т е вот пример такого файла:

```
Столбец1;Столбец2;Столбец3
Столбец1;Столбец2;Столбец3
```

Тут у нас два ряда с тремя столбцами. Можно прям сохранить в файл с названием *some.csv* и открыть в libre office или excel, должно отобразиться нормально в виде таблички.

И вот так, без дополнительных библиотек, можно сделать csv из некоего массива обьектов:

```
import * as FS from 'fs'

const separator = ";"

const exampleData = [
    {name: "Alisa", age: 12},
    {name: "Bob", age: 60},
    {name: "Trololo", age: 35}
]

FS.writeFileSync("some.csv", exampleData.map(row=> `${row.name}${separator}${row.age}`).join("\n"))
```

Получится:

```
Alisa;12
Bob;60
Trololo;35
```

Вот и все :)

Comment: Я конечно занудствую, но в CSV разделителем может быть только запятая и без вариантов! Формат, в котором разделителем может быть что угодно, называется DSV.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf хорошо))